# TreeView with multiple levels but same object type

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I'm trying to create a `TreeView` with multiples levels but only one type (`IPermission`)

Something like this :

```
--[X] Permission1
----[X] Permission1_1
------[] Permission1_1_1
----[] Permission1_2
----[] Permission1_3
--[X]Permission2
```

And with a possibility of selecting each level with a `CheckBox` for example.

Here is my object:

```
public interface IPermission
{
    int ParentID { get; set; }
    int ID { get; set; }
    string Title { get; set; }
    bool Value { get; set; }
    List<IPermission> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I worked with `HierarchicalDataTemplate` / `DataTemplate` / `CompositeCollection` but did not find a solution.

Here is an example of what I've done :

```
            <TreeView>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Nom" ItemsSource="{Binding Permissions}">
                    <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <CheckBox Margin="2" Tag="{Binding Path=Value}" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" FontWeight="SemiBold" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                        <!-- How to display the Children ? -->
                    </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
                </TreeViewItem>
            </TreeView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XAML markup is incorrect.

You need to define an `ItemTemplate` in the `TreeView`, not in the `TreeViewitem`.

Secondly, you need to set the `ItemsSource` of the `HierarchicalDataTemplate` in order to display the objects hierarchy.

Furthermore, why are you binding the `Tag` property of the `CheckBox` instead of using the `IsChecked` property?

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Permissions}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Margin="2" IsChecked="{Binding Value}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontWeight="SemiBold" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate> 
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Comment: Oh perfect ! I was looking for something more complicated... about the `Tag` it was just a test but of course the `IsChecked` property is the right thing to do. Thanks for your help !